# Android Studio Navigation editor shows "Ambiguous type" on fragments

Tags: android, android-studio, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I am trying to create a navigation graph using the editor, but unfortunately it is showing "Ambiguous Type" on all my available fragments. I tried creating a new fragment, but still the same problem.

[image: NAC editor]

This issue results in the editor not showing the destinations that are available in the XML file.

I have cleaned the AS cache and restarted but this didn't fix anything. I started a new project from scratch and there everything seems to work correctly, so somehow there must be something in my project configuration that affects the navigation editor.

Did anyone experience something similar? Any clue what might be happening?

Comment: Does everything work well when you build and run? Are you using the latest Version 3.5?  Android studio has been notoriously buggy when it comes to editing layout files so perhaps updating AS to the latest version might help solve some of your problems.

Comment: Yeah, running seems to work smoothly. I am using AS 3.5 and NAC 2.1.0 dependencies.

Comment: I have same problem. I solved it by changing version `lifecycle-extensions` to `2.1.0` instead of `2.2.0-alpha4`. Hope this helps

Comment: Nice, that made it! It even shows the nav graph, which wasn't available for me before... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you use `lifecycle-extensions` library? If you do, you should aware that you won't be able to use feature that exists in latest version of course.

Comment: The issue came back after some point again, but after updating to `androidx.navigation:navigation-*:2.2.0-rc01` the nav graph is shown again in the visual editor in AS (using AS 3.6 beta 1)

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was because of conflict between two different types of fragment imports. I had this in my `build.gradle`

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:$androidx_fragment_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$androidx_navigation_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$androidx_navigation_version"
```

Since navigation fragment is being imported through `navigation-fragment-ktx`, I removed the `fragment`

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$androidx_navigation_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$androidx_navigation_version"
```

Hopefully someone finds this helpful as well. I could not find answer anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple modules , Make sure the version of the imported Fragment is **consistent**

[image: test]

The dependencies above will cause Navigation **ambiguous type**

*solution*
In everyModule build.gradle

```kotlin
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.2"
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.2'
```

this will override default fragment version 1.1.0  -->   1.2.4

Comment: Man, you save my day.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the modular architecture and the fragment which you have extended is inherits from one of the modules then you should use the navigation fragment dependency with those subsequent modules too.